# IIS7 - Password Protect Development Server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7, passwords

I have a development server running IIS 7.0 with an ASP.NET MVC Web Application, that authenticates using Forms Authentication/Membership.

I need to be able to prevent unauthorized users from viewing this site. Our customers however should be able to enter a simple username/password to gain access.

After they do so, they should be able to interact with the web application using Forms Authentication as if they just came to an unprotected site.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This is an absolute fail/shortfall on IIS7's part. Massive case of over-engineering and short-sightedness from Microsoft here. This should be a one-click "Add cheap dirty popup password" button separate to all of the over-engineered academically beautiful world of complex authentication modules and crap that they have come up with.

Comment: It's surprising the number of duds who seem perfectly willing to accept this and put up with it by writing their own custom wrapper modules and the like. Just total over-engineering people, get with the program. This should be so simple. I am not going to write any custom code to implement a fricking popup password that used to take 2 seconds to configure. There has to be a simple way.

Comment: Glad to see it is not just me having this issue

Answer (score 6):

My previous answer said forms auth and basic http auth could live side by side in II7 integrated mode. I was completely wrong and have since made a simple solution.

Using a custom HttpModule you can add basic auth along side regular forms auth

```
public class CustomBasicAuthHttpModule : IHttpModule
{
    private HttpApplication httpApplicationContext;

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }

    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        this.httpApplicationContext = context;
        context.BeginRequest += this.OnBeginRequest;
        context.EndRequest += this.OnEndRequest;
    }

    private void OnBeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // your logic of checking Auth header goes here
        if (this.httpApplicationContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"] != "Basic base64-encoded-user:pass")
        {
            this.httpApplicationContext.Response.StatusCode = 401;
            this.httpApplicationContext.Response.End();
        }
    }

    private void OnEndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.httpApplicationContext.Response.StatusCode == 401)
        {
            this.httpApplicationContext.Response.AddHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic");
        }
    }
```

then in your web.config

```
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <add name="CustomBasicAuthHttpModule" type="Namespace.CustomBasicAuthHttpModule, AssemblyName"/>
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: Actually it's not just as simple in my case.

Your solution was the first thing I tried - but somehow "basic authentication" interferes with the "forms authentication" of the most basic new MVC project as we all know it from Visual Studio / New Project.

After authenticating via "basic authentication" I get redirected to the default login url whatever I try and my browser is not even permitted to download the Site.css file.

Any ideas?!

Comment: The IIS basic authentication will have nothing to do with the forms authentication, completely different. The way you phrased your question made it sound like you want to block all access to even the forms login page to anyone but your clients, but once past the IIS challenge-response, they'd login through the forms authentication. I don't know how to have IIS authenticate on behalf of sql forms, sorry. I guess I don't get the point either, what's wrong with forms authentication, why would a IIS challenge-response be better?

Comment: You're totally wrong jayrdub. The question was explained well and this is a very common requirement. IIS itself states that "basic authentication cannot be used with any redirect based authentication method such as forms authentication". "Windows authentication" also comes with the same caveat. You can use both basic and windows authentication no problems, providing you don't also have forms authentication running underneath in the application. The OP's question is very legitimate and a common requirement.

Comment: It is super common to have an ASP.Net application that uses "forms authentication" in the application itself. Explanation: This simply would be something such as having a "member login" area of your site - most sites have something like that. THEN you ALSO want to throw a quick and dirty popup password over the ENTIRE site because it is currently in development/test and you don't want random internet surfers coming across it. This is done all the time on IIS6 and unix web servers, why can't IIS7 allow such a simple configuration with a single one click button.

Comment: @Aaron, you're totally right, I don't know why I answered it that way. I edited and added the solution I use

Answer (score 2):

I just did this with [Helicon Ape](http://www.helicontech.com/ape/). The free license includes 3 sites, which for me was good enough.

If you use this on a site, just remember to check if the license is activated for the site (start menu > helicon > ape > manager, help, license manager).

Comment: A third party add-on shouldn't be required for such a simple task.

Comment: No, it shouldn't. Doesn't mean it isn't, sadly.

Answer (score 0):

As Aaron points out, this isn't so straightforward in IIS7. Now, the flip side is this old trick is insecure at best and there are better ways to do it now and being able to use all authenticaiton methods with all apps has lots of advantages. There are some ways to get around this such as:

a) keeping the development site behind a VPN which your clients can access.
b) reverse proxying the site, and letting the proxy do the http authentication.
c) A bit more involved would be to build your app with a demo mode. Trick here is to make it turn on or off from the first request given a special magic query string. Check for that in Session_Start() then tag users that come with it and profit.

Answer (score -1):

We wrote a custom module for IIS to allow certain IP ranges through automatically, and present anyone else with a login dialogue. Once they'd logged in, it stored that fact in their session and simply passed requests through.

Works alright, can be applied to anything in IIS sites or services.

Comment: No good when my ISP gives me a totally random dynamic IP every time. Also no good when I need to give access to a select group of testers or business partners, say 50 of them, who all need to access the dev site. I can't make them all spend an hour each to go fumbling around for their IP address because they are all located in different physical locations and they are business people, not technical people. They have no idea how to obtain their IP address from their router/network config etc. I need to simply be able to email them with a password so they can easily hit the site.